# change position of image when hover effect to css3

Tags: html, css, button

I have a css file that uses an image as button, when user hovers the button the image is realocated to other position like:

```
button.btn,
input[type="submit"].btn {
  *padding-top: 2px;
  *padding-bottom: 2px;
    background: url(http://www.eurekavi.com/ci_crud_1/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/css/images/btn_cancelar.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -3000px;
    width: 80px;

}

button.btn,
input[type="submit"].btn:hover  {
background: url(http://www.eurekavi.com/ci_crud_1/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/css/images/btn_cancelar.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;
    }
```

In html i add the code:

```
<div class="form-button-box">
    <input type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-large" />
</div>
```

After doing this a button will appear holding text that the image has. it works nice.

But then if text is a variable I can not do that, I would have to make a different image for different texts... That is not good.

I would like to generate a input button passing the text of button as attribute and have the same effect, I have two issues:

1. How to generate correct color and get inmediatly to other color when hover.
   (Do you know any good generator) my base color is `#7d7d7d` and final `#272727`
2. how to avoid a strange effect in my button, when hover it is like animating or sliding and not doing it straight away, please take a look at my fiddle

could you please help me acomplish the last button (without that sliding effect, I mean change color inmediatly when hover) [shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewu6M/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make everything with CSS and not use images so you don't have to make a bunch of images for different texts. Check out [this site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to use to generate gradient code quickly. Otherwise, your buttons are fairly simple and can easily be made with CSS. Let me know if I am missing the point of your question.

Comment: you are right, but do you know how to correct the code Or what am I missing as it is not working in my fiddle, also the question is related how to change the color when hovering....